# Capturing a regex pattern does not work with a multi-line string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to read a string that contains multiple lines `\n` included, and it has the following pattern:

```
Total     : 30
================
Loaded    : 27
Loading   : 0
Failed    : 3

Done.. time taken : 3.49  seconds.
=============
2020-03-08 15:39:26
```

The line containing the time taken can sometimes be represented in milliseconds, seconds, or minutes.
So I need to capture the digits before the unit, the unit itself, and the digits represented by `Failed`.

I was able to extract the time duration plus the unit without any issues. Maybe because they both are on the same line.

```
let matches = /taken\D+([\d\.]+)\s+(\w+)/g.exec(trace);
matches[1];  // 3.49
matches[2];  // seconds
```

But when I tried to extract the `Failed` digit, the regular expression does not work.

```
/Failed\s+:\s(\d+).*?taken\D+([\d\.]+)\s+(\w+)/g  
/Failed\s+:\s(\d+).*?taken\D+([\d\.]+)\s+(\w+)/gm  
/Failed\s+:\s(\d+)[.\n\r]*?taken\D+([\d\.]+)\s+(\w+)/g
```

None of that worked.
I know I can do a workaround by removing all new line `\n` characters before performing the regular expression, but I want to know what mistake was done from my part?

```js
let trace = "Total     : 30\n"
          + "================\n"
          + "Loaded    : 27\n"
          + "Loading   : 0\n"
          + "Failed    : 3\n"
          + "\n"
          + "Done.. time taken : 3.49  seconds.\n"
          + "=============\n"
          + "2020-03-08 15:39:26";

let pattern = /Failed\s+:\s+(\d+)[\n\r.]*?taken\D+([\d\.]+)\s+(\w+)/gm;

let matches = pattern.exec(trace);

let failedCount = matches[1];   // should be "3"
let timeTaken   = matches[2];   // should be "3.49"
let timeUnit    = matches[3];   // should be "seconds"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `s` to make the `.` expression include `\n`. like so:

```js
let trace = "Total     : 30\n"
          + "================\n"
          + "Loaded    : 27\n"
          + "Loading   : 0\n"
          + "Failed    : 3\n"
          + "\n"
          + "Done.. time taken : 3.49  seconds.\n"
          + "=============\n"
          + "2020-03-08 15:39:26";

let pattern = new RegExp("Failed\\s+:\\s+(\\d+).*?taken\\D+([\\d\\.]+)\\s+(\\w+)", "s");

let matches = pattern.exec(trace);

let failedCount = matches[1];   // should be "3"
let timeTaken   = matches[2];   // should be "3.49"
let timeUnit    = matches[3];   // should be "seconds"
console.log(failedCount, timeTaken, timeUnit);
```

Comment: I just added the `s` to the regex `/....../gs` and that worked. Thanks

Comment: yes its should. i wrapped it in the `RegExp` object because for some reason the snipped here not support adding `s` at the end, as you do

Comment: but the `g` here look redundant. since you not look for more then one appearance of this expression